# what does the new green legendary tinting mean?

Tags: path-of-exile

see how there are 2 different items with the same name and vastly different prices?
[image]

I played up until Beastiary and played very little of that, but I have never seen this distinction, and the stats appear to be the same on poe.ninja

Answer (score 5):

The green color is not new as it was introduced during the legacy league. That is a [relic version](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Relic) of a unique. Currently in Delve league, you can get these by finding [timeworn reliquary keys](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Timeworn_Reliquary_Key). Those open up the timeworn reliquary (at the map device) which gives up to 3 of any previous league specific unique items with this special green "foil" coloring.

In the Legacy league you could find [ancient reliquary keys](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Ancient_Reliquary_Key) which granted access to the ancient reliquary. In addition to the green "foil" coloring these versions had legacy stats meaning you could find [legacy variants](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_unique_items_with_legacy_variants) of any unique item at the time (for better or worse).

Comment: Just as a sidenote to my answer, the difference in price is just the special coloring. Both versions will have the same stats.